# an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. using Azure Data, entity core

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to create a database with Entity frame work but an error occur.

> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

I try to restart VS code, my PC. Add **TrustServerCertificate=True** to sql connection string but it not work

Answer (score -1):

I find the answer through another post, I resolve this problem by adding **Integrated Security=false** to my connection string

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).